# SplitView with multiple ViewControllers - Storyboards - iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have finished iPhone version of my app and want my app to support iPads as well. I used a tabbar controller for iphone.. I could use the same for iPad, however, I would have too much free space on iPad if I use a Tabbar. so I have decided to use Split View Controller. Left part(table view) should be visible all the time even if it's not in landscape mode. And every time a cell is clicked, the corresponding view should be loaded to the right hand side.. By the way I am using storyboards.. Seems like it makes everything more difficult. Are there some examples of it? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar situation recently. Basically you can use the split view project template to generate the basic code. After that, I created a DetailedViewControllerContainer interface and used it as the view controller for the right side view of the split view, replacing the generated DetailViewController. 
After that I created several view controllers, each of them corresponds to a selection in the left side view(master view controller). And add these view controllers as the child view controllers for the DetailedViewControllerContainer. 
The catch is that you will need to use code to load the child view controllers. The benefit is that the child view controllers do not need to be modified from the iPhone version. The DetailedViewControllerContainer remains the only SplitView delegate.

Take a look at the sample code I wrote on github:
https://github.com/raoying/SplitView-Sample